# Setting up the translation in RascalMPL

Tags: rascal

How do I setup the translation(source-to-source transformation) for my Rascal project? A link to any repository that shows how it is done will also be highly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/GettingStarted/ howto download and install Rascal.

In https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Recipes/ you can find many small examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already had rascal running but I was asking how do I register actions like parse, transformations on VSCode such that they can be called from the VSCode menu?